# how to show only 3 items of this loop ? node.js EJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

If there are more than 3 items in this loop, then I want to add a "show more button" to show the rest of the items

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<div class='container'>
    <p><a class='btn btn-primary btn-large'href='/items/new'>Add new item</a>/p>

    //loop
    <% items.forEach(function(item){ %>
        <div>
            <h4><%=item.name%></h4>
            <img src='<%=item.image%>'>
        </div>
    <% }); %>    
</div>

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Comment: i want only to show the first 3 items of this loop and if the items are more than 3 i want to add a button looks like 'show all items' so you can show rest of the items  in order to enhance the UX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) provides more arugments, the 2nd one is the index.

Something like this should work

```
//loop
<% items.forEach(function(item, idx){ %>
    <% if (idx < 4) { %>
    <div>
        <h4><%=item.name%></h4>
        <img src='<%=item.image%>'>
    </div>
<% }); %>

<% if (items.length > 3) { %>
    <div>
        <button>Show More</button>
    </div>
<% }; %>
```